# Выбор СУБД для приложения

Tags: c#, sql

На внешнем сервере будет находится 2 приложения. Первое приложение ежесекундно берет данные из потока в интернете и каждую минуту заносит в БД конечный результат данных. Второе приложение будет отлавливать событие добавления данных в БД и затем будет брать новую добавленную строку для своих расчетов каждую минуту. Ранее использовал всегда SQLite для простоты переноса БД на разные устройства.

- Есть ли какая-нибудь разница в разных СУБД для таких нужд? Или
  скорость будет приблизительно одинаковой для данных задач?
- И что лучше, хранить БД на сервере, устанавливая всё, или же просто в
  файле, в случае SQLite?

Comment: К WPF и вообще Visual Studio больше всего подходит SQL Server. Попробуй на нем. По скорости не жалуюсь :)

Comment: *Есть ли какая-нибудь разница в разных СУБД для таких нужд?* Два клиента по одному запросу в минуту? да хоть на CSV делай - без разницы. Городить для такой задачи сервер БД - по-моему, сверхизбыточно.

Comment: Как должна повлиять на ответ информация о том, что это WPF-приложение? WinForms или консольные работаю с БД по особенному? Пожалуйста, используйте метки по назначению

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я указываю избыточную информацию для общего понимания, хоть это и не имеет смысла, возможно

Comment: @Fresto, мне интересны вопросы по wpf, я захожу в тему, а вопроса по wpf здесь нет. Избыточная информация в тексте вопроса может быть, но в метках она уж точно не нужна.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хорошо, в след раз буду это учитывать, спасибо)

Comment: @АндрейNOP да и по сути тут тег c# тоже избыточен

Comment: @ГеннадийП, ну это не совсем так, например, зная что используется одна технология MS, можно смело рекомендовать другие их технологии, так как они для работы между собой обычно хорошо "заточены"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно делать такие примитивные запросы, как вы описали, то подойдет в принципе любая СУБД, так как для .NET есть адаптеры под многие СУБД.

Как бесплатный и в тоже время лишенных всяких излишеств подойдет какой-нибудь MySQL.

Если в ресурсах вы не ограничены и есть перспективы того, что в будущем придется пилить монстроозные статистические запросы, то можно взять "Больших братьев" MS SQL,Oracle, Postgres (вроде, тоже бесплатный), так как в них много аналитических функций и фишек:

Но я бы предпочел MS SQL если есть перспективы развития БД, так как открываются многие фишки, например можно писать CLR сборки на C# и использовать их в СУБД.

Comment: За что минус...?

Comment: Задача слишком простая чтобы выбирать сервер исходя из таких фишек как CLR сборки на C#.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да. Поэтому я написал с оговоркой на перспективы

Answer (score 2):

Отловить событие добавления строки в БД нормальным образом вы не сможете ни в одной СУБД - в итоге все сведется к опросу БД по таймеру. Если такой вариант вас устраивает - можете использовать любую СУБД.

В противном случае я бы порекомендовал использовать сетевое взаимодействие: пусть первое приложение посылает данные второму напрямую. Для этих целей удобно будет использовать WCF с привязкой NetTcpBinding: она как раз двунаправленная, т.е. позволяет реализовать нормальную модель "публикация-подписка". В случае недоступности WCF можно использовать ZeroMQ или сделать свой велосипед на tcp сокетах.

Comment: А что на счет триггеров у SQL Server? Там, как раз, самые основные - это отлавливание добавление\удаление записей в таблице.

Comment: @Fresto но через триггеры вы не дёрнете ваше приложение. они работают строго внутри базы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Теоритически можно дернуть через xp_cmdshell, но это костыль.

Comment: Так подождите, а на C# же пишут триггеры под SQL Server. Где вызываются функции, когда в БД изменяются данные

Comment: @Fresto эти функции работают в очень ограниченном окружении, много там не сделать, максимум - отправить сетевой запрос. Но зачем это делать из триггера - когда можно сделать то же самое вообще без лишнего звена в виде СУБД?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ну, фишка в том, что проще иметь что-то централизованное, где будут все данные храниться. Потому что из первой программы данные записываются в историю, т.е. мне они нужны будут потом для работы и не в единичном варианте, а за месяц-год..